# Some problem with harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhFQZ.jpg)

I don’t know how can deduce this conclusion  by Cauchy’s formula when {1}{w-a}is harmonic.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I’m sorry ,this is my first time to ask in this website .